# How to set file association for all users when installing an app

Tags: windows, installation, registry

I have two applications that are handlers for the same extension(for example `.abc`). I used an MSDN [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-intro) when developing applications. I've registered my extension and applications in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. After some testing I found out that all my registrations are overwritten by `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\<.abc>` setting. My applications are installed per machine, not per user. So, is there any way to create a file association for all users on the machine?

Comment: Ha e you read the [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) yet? Don't write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT if you need global settings, write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead. But user-specific settings always take priority over global settings.

Comment: Also, worth noting: https://woshub.com/managing-default-file-associations-in-windows-10/ "*The main difference between Windows 10/11 and previous Windows versions is that you can’t manage file association settings through the Registry or the “Open With” feature of the Group Policy Preferences.*"